# javafx.fxml.LoadException Unable to run .java

Tags: java, fxml

My code simply doesn't run. Previously it couldn't find the .fxml file. After cleaning the solution I got this error.I believe the main problem lies here. I've uploaded the full error in pastebin. My FXML is under src with the rest of the .java files

https://pastebin.com/guKHAG3p

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
  /C:/Users/jinyi/Desktop/CIS%2022C/CoronavirusUpdate/bin/fxml.fxml

```
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2625)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2603)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3237)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3194)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3163)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3136)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3113)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3106)
at CoronavirusUpdateMain.start(CoronavirusUpdateMain.java:12)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
... 1 more
```

My main

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setResizable(false);
    stage.setMaxWidth(596);
    stage.setMaxHeight(280);

    stage.show();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="280.0" prefWidth="596.0" style="-fx-background-color: #fff;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="mainController">
    <children>
      <GridPane layoutX="133.0" layoutY="70.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="163.0" prefWidth="358.0" style="-fx-background-color: E8EAF6;" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="47.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="133.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="105.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="70.0">
        <columnConstraints>
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints maxHeight="45.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="45.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints maxHeight="55.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="37.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <Label alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="111.0" style="-fx-background-color: #303F9F;" text="Select Country :" textFill="WHITE">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Arial Bold" size="14.0" />
               </font>
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="2.0" left="2.0" right="2.0" top="2.0" />
               </GridPane.margin>
            </Label>
            <ComboBox fx:id="comboBox" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" onAction="#getData" promptText="Countries" style="-fx-background-color: #E8EAF6;" GridPane.columnIndex="1">
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="2.0" left="2.0" right="2.0" top="2.0" />
               </GridPane.margin>
            </ComboBox>
            <Label alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="41.0" prefWidth="122.0" style="-fx-background-color: #C5CAE9;" text="Cases :" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Arial Bold" size="14.0" />
               </font>
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="2.0" left="2.0" right="2.0" top="2.0" />
               </GridPane.margin>
            </Label>
            <Label alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="111.0" style="-fx-background-color: #C5CAE9;" text="Deaths :" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Arial Bold" size="14.0" />
               </font>
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="2.0" left="2.0" right="2.0" top="2.0" />
               </GridPane.margin>
            </Label>
            <Label alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="111.0" style="-fx-background-color: #C5CAE9;" text="Population:" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Arial Bold" size="14.0" />
               </font>
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="2.0" left="2.0" right="2.0" top="2.0" />
               </GridPane.margin>
            </Label>
            <Label fx:id="lcases" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="111.0" style="-fx-background-color: #C5CAE9;" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Arial Bold" size="12.0" />
               </font>
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="2.0" left="2.0" right="2.0" top="2.0" />
               </GridPane.margin>
               <graphic>
                  <Label fx:id="ldeaths1" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="111.0" style="-fx-background-color: #C5CAE9;">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="Arial Bold" size="12.0" />
                     </font>
                     <graphic>
                        <Label fx:id="totalCases" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="111.0" style="-fx-background-color: #C5CAE9;">
                           <font>
                              <Font name="Arial Bold" size="12.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Label>
                     </graphic>
                  </Label>
               </graphic>
            </Label>
            <Label fx:id="totalDeaths" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="111.0" style="-fx-background-color: #C5CAE9;" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Arial Bold" size="12.0" />
               </font>
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="2.0" left="2.0" right="2.0" top="2.0" />
               </GridPane.margin>
            </Label>
            <Label fx:id="pop" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="111.0" style="-fx-background-color: #C5CAE9;" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Arial Bold" size="12.0" />
               </font>
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="2.0" left="2.0" right="2.0" top="2.0" />
               </GridPane.margin>
            </Label>
            <Label fx:id="worldPop" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="111.0" style="-fx-background-color: #C5CAE9;" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Arial Bold" size="12.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Label fx:id="worldTotalDeaths" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="111.0" style="-fx-background-color: #C5CAE9;" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Arial Bold" size="12.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Label fx:id="worldTotalCase" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="111.0" style="-fx-background-color: #C5CAE9;" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Arial Bold" size="12.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
         </children>
      </GridPane>
      <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="62.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="41.0" prefWidth="458.0" style="-fx-background-color: #3F51B5;" text="Countries where COVID-19 has spread" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font name="Aparajita Bold" size="27.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: See line 43 in [linked output](https://pastebin.com/guKHAG3p): *Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: **This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 81***

Comment: @Andreas my chrome driver is 81 I've previously used the same driver and it works

Comment: Yes, line 1 says "Starting ChromeDriver 81.0.4044.138", so we know it's ChromeDriver version 81, but the error is not about the *ChromeDriver* version, but about the ***Chrome*** version, or rather the incompatibility of the *ChromeDriver* version vs. whatever *Chrome* version you have.

Comment: @Andreas Seems like my chrome got automatically updated without my knowledge. That helped. Thanks!